# ILmerge generating only 64bit compatible exe

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, ilmerge

I am building up my VS2010 project using "any cpu configuration" so that the executable can work for both 32 bit and 64 bit versions.

But after using ILMerge to generate a bundled exe, the resultant exe is only working in 64 bit system and for 32 bit system its showing

```
This version of output.exe is not compatible with the version of Windows you're running. Check your computer's system information to see whether you need a x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit) version of the program, and then contact the software publisher.
```

The ILMerge command used:

```
C:\BuildTools\ilmerge.exe /out:proj1.exe output.exe 1.dll NLog.dll 2.dll targetplatform:v4 /ndebug
```

I tried to figure out any option in ILMerge to fix this, but do not find anything useful.

Any help on this will be of great help.

Comment: "3 bit system its showing "non compatibility" error" is not an adequate problem description.

Comment: It is the kind of error you'll get when you try to run a .NET 4.5 program on Windows XP.  Don't omit details of the machine you are trying to run this on.

Comment: The system is running `Windows 7 32 bit OS`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out is the issue with Nlog.dll which was built in 64 bit environment. Fixed after converting it to Any Cpu